# RestAssured Post call with body throws an error "java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed. Expected status code <200> but was <415>."

Tags: java, junit, rest-assured

```
@Test
public void testPost() throws URISyntaxException {
    AgencyRequest agencyRequest = new AgencyRequest();
    agencyRequest.setConnectorId(1);
    agencyRequest.setJobConfig("/usr/local/workspace/test.config.xml");
    agencyRequest.setConnectorName("/usr/local/workspace/test.kjb");
    agencyRequest.setRequestId(1);
    agencyRequest.setTenantId(1);
    agencyRequest.setTenantName("Test Tenant");
    agencyRequest.setTimeZone("UTC");

    String json = new Gson().toJson(agencyRequest);
    System.out.println(json);
    System.out.println(uri + "/" + ResourceConstants.JOB_CONFIG);
    given().
    accept(ContentType.JSON).
    body(json).
    post(new URI(uri + "/" + ResourceConstants.JOB_CONFIG)).
    then().
    assertThat().
    statusCode(HttpStatus.OK_200);
}
```

If I run the same test on Postman by choosing the post method and content type as json and with the body, it gave the response status code as 200. But my unit test is not passed. In the body, I have tried passing the json string as you see before as well as I tried passing the java object, both fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the content type of request while sending the request. Consider making the given change

```
   .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
```

Comment: It works, but i'm confused. If you look at my above code I have specified accept(ContentType.JSON). I assumed which is my post body content type. Can you please describe the difference between accept and contentType

Comment: @MuthaiahPL - accept(ContentType.JSON) means that you are telling the server that you expect the response in Json format whereas setting up contentType(ContentType.JSON) means that you are informing the server about the type of data you are sending in request.

Comment: Can you please answer this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388415/restassured-post-call-with-nested-object-throws-an-error-java-lang-assertionerr

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to the top of your code:

```
.log().all()
        .config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(encoderconfig.appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false)))
.header()....
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This change will work, try it.

```
.header("Content-Type", "application/json").contentType(ContentType.JSON).accept(ContentType.JSON)
```